# Window resizing on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im Currently working on a custom calendar, and i very much like the way that google calendar resizes in order to better fit the current screen size, Ive looked through out google but just cant seem to find how they do it. Do they resize the entire page or just the table divs? and is there a way to achieve this with pure css? Im under the impression that you can calculate the resolution with javascript and/or jquery and redo the css from that, but if its possible with good old css, all the better. this isnt one of those. GIIME TE CODES posts. But a good explanation of the mechanics behind this functionality would benefit a lot more than just me im sure, kudos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, pure CSS is the easiest way to achieve this. You should look into [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and fluid page layouts. These are used in [responsive web design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) to change the layout of the page based on the size of the browser window.

As far as I can see the google calendar simply changes the width of each column of the calendar, so it shouldn't be too difficult at all.

You could use media queries along with a fluid layout to achieve this in my opinion, possibly even a better outcome than google have achieved, as when you have a very small window size the google calendar doesn't work too well!

Hope this proves helpful :)

Comment: Using media queries would essentially mean that i need a stylesheet, or style call, for each and every resolution?

Comment: Well the point of the media queries is not to change the width of the calendar, it is just to change the layout on smaller resolutions to provide a layout more suited for the small browser. On Google Calendar, when you resize the window to be very small, the size of each date box becomes very small - a media query could be used to change the layout from having them all across, trying to squash the whole month into the small width of the window, to just making all the days stack below one another and taking up the whole width. For basic use, just using a fluid layout is sufficient however.